# How to install gource with homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to install gource via homebrew. It yields in the following error:

```
$ brew install  gource 
==> Downloading https://github.com/acaudwell/Gource/releases/download/gource-0.41/gource-0.41.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /opt/boxen/cache/homebrew/gource-0.41.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/gource/0.41 --without-x
checking for IMG_LoadJPG_RW... yes
checking for boostlib >= 1.46... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available... yes
configure: error: Could not link against -lGLU !
```

How can I install gource?

Comment: It looks like the Homebrew receipe is missing a dependency - report it as a bug

Answer (score 1):

[Brew issue #22025](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/22025) discusses problems installing grouce and a work around.

Do the instructions in this issue help you? If not, please follow the [brew troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting) to report the problem.